# How to post an mutable array to web service using ASIFormdata

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am doing an iphone application,in that i have to post multiple images at a time.For that i convert every image in to data format and added to an array.so i have to post entire array to the web service, so please kindly help me. (OR please give any alternative).thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this automatically.  You can post them using Multipart Form posting, but you would have to construct the POST data explicitly.

See this question: [iPhone ASIFormDataRequest with multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282726/iphone-asiformdatarequest-with-multipart-form-data)